# tr1::functional error with g++ 4.8.1

Tags: c++, c++11, tr1, g++4.8

Code:

```
    #include <tr1/functional>

    class Test
    {
    public:
        Test() { ; }
        virtual void foo() = 0;
    };

    void someFunc(Test& j)
    {
        j.foo();
    }

    void func(Test& j)
    {
       std::tr1::bind(someFunc, std::tr1::ref(j));
    }
```

Using g++ 4.8.1 on Linux, compiling with `--std=c++11` I get:

```
    In file included from foo.cpp:1:0:
    /usr/include/c++/4.8.1/tr1/functional: In instantiation of ‘class std::tr1::reference_wrapper<Test>’:
    foo.cpp:17:44:   required from here
    /usr/include/c++/4.8.1/tr1/functional:495:9: error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type ‘Test’
             operator()(_Args&... __args) const
             ^
    foo.cpp:3:7: note:   because the following virtual functions are pure within ‘Test’:
     class Test
           ^
    foo.cpp:7:18: note:     virtual void Test::foo()
         virtual void foo() = 0;
                      ^
```

This doesn't seem to make any sense. Using the corresponding boost classes works fine. Can someone confirm this is a TR1 bug in G++ 4.8.1?

Comment: Works fine with the non-TR1 `std::` C++11 equivalents on GCC 4.8.

Comment: @stefan, `main()` is not needed to compile it, only if you try to link it.

Comment: If you have access to GCC4.8 (i.e. A C++11-ready compiler) why are you using the technical reports?

Comment: @stefan, if you just add `main()` running the code tells you nothing, you still don't execute `func`. The question is about a compilation error, not run-time behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The libstdc++ `tr1::reference_wrapper` implementation has this:

```
  template<typename... _Args>
    typename result_of<_M_func_type(_Args...)>::type
    operator()(_Args&... __args) const
    {
      return __invoke(get(), __args...);
    }
```

The `result_of` expression uses a by-value `_M_func_type` parameter (which is the template parameter of the `reference_wrapper` i.e. `Test`), so it tries to form the function type `Test()`, which uses a by-value `Test` return type, which is invalid for an incomplete or abstract type.  I think I fixed this for `std::reference_wrapper` ages ago, it needs to use `result_of<_M_func_type&(Args...)>`.

The TR1 implementation in libstdc++ is not really maintained any longer - TR1 served its purpose but its time has passed.